# What is reg property in device tree?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

What is `address-cell` and `size-cells` in the device tree? Is `reg` is related to `address-cell` and `size-cell`? If yes, then how?

For example:

```
memory: memory@20000000 { 
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            device_type = "memory";
            reg = <0x20000000 0x80000000>;
    };
```

What is 0x20000000 ? from where we can get this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The meaning of reg depends on the type of bus the device is connected to and is documented in the device tree binding for the bus.

Here, memory is directly mapped in the CPU address space and reg is `<address size>`.

So, this means that your DDR is starts at address `0x20000000` and has a size of 2GB.

This address is supposed to be documented in the SoC datasheet if you can get it, in a sections that is named memories or memory maps.

Comment: What is address cells and size cells ?

Comment: There are not useful and should not be used because memory is not a bus. It would give the number of address cells and number of size cells for the reg property of child nod of a bus.

Comment: Then why address-cells and size-cells = <1> or <0> or <2>. different values

Comment: @PankajSuryawanshi All numbers in the device tree are 32-bit. `#address-cells = <1>;` means the address consists of a single 32-bit number in the `reg` property. `#size-cells = <1>;` means the size consists of a single 32-bit number in the `reg` property. The `reg` property contains the address cells in big-endian order, followed by the size cells in big-endian order. So if `#address-cells = <2>; #size-cells = <2>;`, then the `reg` property would contain 4 values: `reg = <ADDR_HI_32_BITS ADDR_LO_32_BITS SIZE_HI_32_BITS SIZE_LO_32_BITS>;`.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the reg property describes the offset and the quantity of the memory or the device mapped.
So

```
reg = <0x20000000 0x80000000>
```

means that: "Starting from the register 0x20000000, next 0x80000000 bytes are mapped for this device".

#address-cells specifies the number of 32 bit registers that will be required to specify the starting address.
Since, 0x20000000 is a 32 bit value,

```
#address-cells = <1>;
```

Similarly, #size-cells specifies the number of bytes required to encode the size field.
Since 0x80000000 is a u32 value,
#size-cells = <1>;

Do refer the website: [devicetree.org](https://github.com/devicetree-org/devicetree-specification/releases/tag/v0.4)